# Why is the ‘auto’ storage class specifier included in C?

Tags: history, programming, c, design-choices

The `auto` keyword in C seems quite redundant: wherever it makes sense to define a variable with automatic storage duration, it is already the default, so there is no reason to use the keyword. The keyword is so useless that C++11 managed to repurpose it for type deduction, with impunity: the change made virtually no impact on syntax-compatibility with C code.

We do know, however, that some seemingly superfluous syntactical features of C, like the `register` keyword (made mostly obsolete by modern register allocators) and [the `->` operator](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10812/), did serve some purpose historically, even if they are mostly redundant now. I would assume the same is the case with `auto`.

Why was the `auto` storage class specifier added to C? Was it inherited from another language? Included ‘for completeness’? Is there a document that provides a rationale for its existence?

Comment: When processing code which the gcc optimizer cannot be trusted to process meaningfully, the `register` storage qualifier can offer a huge performance boost, sometimes allowing loops to execute just as fast in `-O0` mode as they would with optimizations enabled.

Comment: "The keyword is so useless that C++11 managed to repurpose it for type deduction" C++ is not C. A C code is not necessarily a valid C++ code

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: C++ is not C, but it maintains syntax compatibility with C to a large extent. The fact that repurposing the `auto` keyword had so little impact on that is quite remarkable.

Comment: fair enough I never used `auto` in C code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation about `->` has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117287/discussion-on-question-by-user3840170-why-was-the-auto-storage-class-specifier).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no one ever used it in C++ either. That's why C++11 repurposed it for auto type deduction

Comment: Back in the day (Aztec C compiler for Z-80 in the early 80s), the `register` keyword was quite handy. That compiler did very little optimizing - so little that I was able to disassemble machine code and pretty much decompile the result in my head. One we had working code, we'd go back and selectively add `register` here and there to speed things up

Comment: Just for completeness. The repurposing of `auto` for type deduction came from the D language where it was used for that purpose for a very long time now. Long before C++ even contemplated it. Contrary to C++ auto is still categorized as storage category, which means that type inference works by omitting the type and the rvalue's type is taken for the type of the declared variable. `auto a=whatever`, `const a=whatever`, `immutable a=whatever` and `static a=whatever` all are valid declarations inferring the type of a from the type of `whatever`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It wasn't added in C; it was inherited from B.  The [B Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) didn't have types, so there no way to declare a variable local to function without using the `auto` keyword.

So, for example, you might have a B function something like:

```
add(a, b) {
    auto ret;
    ret = a + b;
    return ret;
}
```

Because of the default `int` rule in C, that's also [a valid C program](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EKa4cG), and it is equivalent to this modern "ANSI C" version:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    int ret;
    ret = a + b;
    return ret;
}
```

I'm not sure there was any rationale for including the `auto` keyword in C other than it allowed most existing B programs to be valid C programs.

Comment: I realised it came from B soon after posting the question. Still I wonder, was it common to declare variables with `auto` in C? Was it an actual consideration to be syntax-compatible with B? Or was the compatibility there because B *evolved* into C, and nobody bothered to remove the keyword?

Comment: @user3840170 I'm pretty sure it was a deliberate decision to be compatible with B. If that compatibility wasn't a goal Dennis Ritchie would've probably made bigger changes and fewer B programs would have been valid C programs, even today. The incompatible changes C did make were for more glaring problems with B, like changing the character escape character from an asterisk to a backslash (eg. `'*n'` to `'\n'`, and changing compound assignment operators to be of the form `op=` instead of `=op`. That last change also got picked up by more modern versions of B.

Comment: From what I understand `=op` was possible on very early C as well.

Comment: But why is B's choice of the asterisk as the escape character a "glaring problem"?

Comment: Probably better to link to [the B reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20150611114642/https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bref.html) instead of Wikipedia.

Comment: The `=op` to `op=` change certainly makes far more sense, consider the line `x=-2;` vs `x= -2;`  In C (and most C-like languages) these are identical.  In B, that space makes the difference between subtracting 2 from x and setting x to -2, completely different.

Answer (score 15):

The keyword was inherited from B.

[B](https://web.archive.org/web/20150611114642/https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bref.html) was a programming language with no type system at all: every variable held a machine word (corresponding to the `int` type in C), and the type of each value was determined by the operation performed. Since there was no type to specify for variables, the only thing to declare about a variable was its storage class; unlike in C, the default in B corresponded to C’s `static`, i.e. a variable that existed for the duration of the whole program’s run time. Thus the `auto` keyword was included to denote automatic variables, which existed only for the duration of a single function call. The term *automatic* itself came from PL/I, from which B also borrowed the `/* ... */` comment syntax.

While C added type declarations, `int` was kept as the implicit default, and it was still possible to declare `int` variables with only the storage class specifier, just like in B. In the early days of C, it was common to rely on this. Here’s for example [the famous Duff’s device from 1983](http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/duffs_device):

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n=(count+7)/8;
    switch(count%8){
    case 0: do{ *to = *from++;
    case 7:     *to = *from++;
    case 6:     *to = *from++;
    case 5:     *to = *from++;
    case 4:     *to = *from++;
    case 3:     *to = *from++;
    case 2:     *to = *from++;
    case 1:     *to = *from++;
        }while(--n>0);
    }
}
```

Duff omits any type specifiers for the `count` parameter, the `n` variable and the return type of `send`; all are assumed to be `int`. (Since he doesn’t actually return any value from the function, he would have probably used `void` for the return type in modern C, but [that barely existed back then](https://web.archive.org/web/20080731144110/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html).) The K&R-style declaration for function parameters he uses for the `send` function is also a straightforward extension of B syntax.

We can therefore surmise that the `auto` keyword was included ‘for symmetry’ with other storage class specifiers, to support this coding style that relied on implicit `int`; this also eased porting B code into C. Whether compatibility with B code was an explicit goal or just an emergent property coming from the fact that the first C compiler grew out of a B compiler, I don’t know. But it was probably a consideration.

Over the years, implicit `int` fell into disuse (with contemporary compilers emitting warnings against it), and with it, the `auto` keyword as well. (I’d assume `auto` was never popular in C in the first place, as `int` is one character shorter, so everyone declared the type anyway.) With the B language extinct, and B-derived K&R C displaced by ISO C, the keyword became redundant.

Answer (score 5):

#### Minority report:

user3840170 answered:

> I’d assume auto was never popular in C in the first place, as int is one character shorter, so everyone declared the type anyway.

Some of us more anal retentive types *always* used "auto":

```
auto int x;
auto int y;
```

as two lines, never as:

```
int x, y;
```

It made it much easier to find all the declarations by simply searching for "auto".

Or perhaps it was over-reaction to finding:

```
char*  x,y;
```

wasting time wondering if that's what they really meant, and having to rewrite it as:

```
auto char *x;
auto char  y;
```

if it actually was correct.

Things like:

```
char *x, *rindex(), *y;
```

where implicit "auto" and "extern" were combined, were annoying too.

Asking "*Why is the ‘auto’ storage class specifier included in C?*" is the wrong question.
It should be "*Why wasn't the 'auto' storage class specifier **required** in C?*".
To me it makes even less sense than leaving the "e" off "creat()".

---

Note: this answer was inspired by a similar frustration (about making things more complicated by simplifying them) that I just commented in Chinese.SE [Is pinyin an accurate pronunciation guide?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42153/is-pinyin-an-accurate-pronunciation-guide):

> @goPlayerJuggler says "*once you understand its (sometimes quite counter-intuitive) rules*".
> Ironically (to an outsider at least), those complicating rules were done in the name of simplification.
> E.g. When a "ü" is used where a "u" would be illegal, then omit the umlaut — The sequence "ui" is never legal, so omit the "e" from sequence "uei".

Which is why "Feng shuei" is spelled "Feng shui", and commonly mispronounced as a result.

Comment: I just put one declaration per line without using the `auto` keyword.  It wasn't too hard to find them since they'd be at the start of the function.

Comment: In a well factored program, finding declarations is not hard. It's when you start doing 10-page functions, that leave side effects and horribleness that it's hard. I agree pinyin is nutso though.

Comment: As someone who didn't write any C in the 80s I don't understand the first examples. I can understand why you wouldn't want `int a,b;` (and particularly not the pointer examples!) but not why you'd need `auto` for the counter example instead of simply `int a; int b;`.

Comment: @Voo, `g/auto/p` would list all the declarations. (For context, consider that in the early 80s, my terminal's modem had a light that indicated "HS" for when it was able to make a High Speed connection, 1200 baud as opposed to 300 baud. That's .0012 Mb/s.)

Comment: @Ray Ah yes I missed that, makes sense..